# Миграция на Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer и JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, rider

Нужно что бы работало вот так [First EF Core Console Application](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx)

Создал проект ConsoleApplication (.Net)

Вот что выдаёт

```
D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2>dotnet run
Не удается запустить проект.
Убедитесь в том, что тип проекта поддерживает запуск и что "dotnet run" поддерживает этот проект.
Запускаемый проект должен быть предназначен для TFM с поддержкой запуска (например, netcoreapp2.0) и иметь тип выходных данных "Exe".
Текущий OutputType - "Exe".

D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2>dotnet run
Не удается запустить проект.
Убедитесь в том, что тип проекта поддерживает запуск и что "dotnet run" поддерживает этот проект.
Запускаемый проект должен быть предназначен для TFM с поддержкой запуска (например, netcoreapp2.0) и иметь тип выходных данных "Exe".
Текущий OutputType - "Exe".

D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2>dotnet migrate
No project.json file found in 'D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2'.
Сбой миграции.

D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2>dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine версии 15.6.84.34536 для .NET Core
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.104\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3927,5): error MSB4062: Невозможно загрузить задачу "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles" из сборки "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".  Проверьте правильность объявления <UsingTask>, доступность сборки со всеми ее зависимостями и наличие в задаче общего класса, реализующего Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2
\Book_Base2.csproj]

D:\MailCloud\C#\Rider_Project_JetBrains_C#\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2>
```

Установил `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, как показано в уроке, но не работает миграция, да и dotnet тоже, хотя dotnet restore и build, работают. Может я не туда ввожу? Что делать? и команда dotnet ef тоже не работает. Пишет "Команда не найдена". В Visual Studio 2017 работает, через консоль Nuget, а в Rider ни в какую.

Так же всё по инструкции, пробовал сделать на .NetCore проекте  Установил =>

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Встало всё без ошибок.

Пробовал по этой инструкции [Начало работы с EF Core в приложении .NET Core Console с новой базой данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite)

Всё работало до пункта `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` 
Выдаёт по прежнему

```
D:\MailCloud\CSharp\Rider_Project_JetBrains_CSharp\Book_Base_SQL\Book_Base2\ConsoleApp.SQLite>dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Не найден исполняемый файл, соответствующий команде "dotnet-ef".
```

Может кто нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: Проблема была в том что нужно отдельно пакет Microsoft.Net Core SDK поставить и всё.! Ну и конечно все команды другие ! Вот по этой статье (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81405/discussion-on-question-by-j-atisto---microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sq).

Answer (score 1):

Решается всё установкой пакет Microsoft.Net Core SDK(ver.).Если ввести `dotnet ef` То должна появиться надпись EF и единорог, это означает что всё работает! Вот по этой статье [Install Entity Framework Core](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/install-entity-framework-core.aspx) дальше по урокам всё описывается и команды dotnet тоже есть.

Устанавливал пакеты я так.
В Rider выделяем проект и нажимаем F4, после `<PropertyGroup>` вставляем

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

И Rider поставить всё что нужно.

Взял инфу по установки с этого [Running Entity Framework (Core) commands in Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/) сайта.

Answer (score 1):

[Это помогло в моем случае](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8996#issuecomment-326849252)

Необходимо заменить **PackageReference** на **DotNetCliToolReference** для пакета `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="###" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="###" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="###" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="###" />
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="###" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

Вы должны находится в той же папке где находится `csproj`.

```
dotnet restore
dotnet ef
```